# Entity Data Model in MVC Architecture?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have created a entity data model in my MVC application.  After creating I did some changes in the database.  Should I create my entity model again or is there any way I can just update the entity model?

Please tell me

Thanks, Ritz

Answer (score 0):

Use the Entity Update Model Wizard, [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716705.aspx) some info on it.